# Upload pdf files to MongoDB with ExpressJS,Multer,NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I am in need of help as I feel like I tried everything and nothing works.

I am trying to upload a pdf to MongoDB via my nodejs - expressjs web application and make it available for viewing and download to visitors.

Req.file is detecting the file I try to upload but the moment I try to assign it to the new ItemSchema it returns undefined.

Multer is installed too but I don't know if I need to do anything with it to assign MongoDB as storage or something. Currently using it with Cloudinary for serving images.

here is the schema of the collection that will hold the pdf if I ever make it work...

```
const schedulePDFSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: `SchedulePDF - ${date.toDateString()}`
  },
  myFile: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  }
});
```

And this is my post route:

```
router.post("/schedulePDF", isLoggedin, isAdmin,  async(req,res)=>{
    const schedulePDF = new SchedulePDFModel({
        myFile : req.file
    });
    console.log(schedulePDF, req.file);
    await schedulePDF.save();
    req.flash('success', 'schedulePDF uploaded!');
    res.redirect('/dash');
});
```

What's wrong with these two?

Thanks in advance.! As always.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Req.file is detecting the file I try to upload but the moment I try to assign it to the new ItemSchema it returns undefined."

Comment: @CherryDT when I console.log(request.file) without me trying to push it to a Mongoose Schema, I get on my terminal the file I tried to upload, "November_Schedule.pdf" for example.

But when I try to push the file to a Mongoose schema like I am trying to do at the code I typed above I get undefined on my terminal when I console.log(req.file)

Comment: That's not logical, you nowhere write to `req.file`. Please show the two exact versions of the code and their two exact output, thanks.

Comment: @CherryDT req.file is dead center in my post route.

What you are asking me to do is the following.
Code that req.file returns undefined:

router.post("/schedulePDF", isLoggedin, isAdmin,  async(req,res)=>{
    const schedulePDF = new SchedulePDFModel({
        myFile : req.file
    });
    console.log(schedulePDF, req.file);
    await schedulePDF.save();
    req.flash('success', 'schedulePDF uploaded!');
    res.redirect('/dash');
});

Code that logs the file name:

router.post("/schedulePDF", isLoggedin, isAdmin,  async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.file);
});

Comment: Add it to your question and show the _exact_ output. It's still not making sense, for example also because you said it logs the "file name" when it fact it should log a whole file object. I can only assume something else asynchronously removes the file object but then that is unrelated to the database operation, setTimeout would do the same. Remember that on Stack Overflow we expect a minimal reproducable example, and what you showed here is neither reproducable nor does it give us all the information that you would get when running the code, such as exact verbatim outputs.

Answer (score 0):

req.file will come out as an object. Target the filename instead like req.file.filename